# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) in getMarket from package betfair

Tags: r, namespaces, environment, betfair

I'm having some problems with the `getMarket` function from package **betfair**. Here's the gist of it:

```
g <- function(x){
    getMarket(x)
}
g(110501389)
```

This throws:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'x' not found
```

`g` is in the global environment, and `getMarket` is from namespace:betfair.

I've never had this problem with other packages (e.g., **mlogit**). Any ideas?

`traceback()` gives:

```
10: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
9: eval(parameters[[j]])
8: FUN(1:2[[1L]], ...)
7: lapply(1:length(parameters), function(j) { ...
6: paste(lapply(1:length(parameters), function(j) { ...
5: .list2xml(parameters, allowNull)
4: paste(body, .list2xml(parameters, allowNull), sep = "")
3: .bfapi(match.call(), service = service)
2: getMarket(y) at .active-rstudio-document#2
1: g(110501389)
```

Comment: What's `getMarket`? and what's the output of `traceback()` after the error occurs?

Comment: real messy output from traceback(); getMarket() is a function in package betfair

Comment: seems like a bug in getMarket. Could you try to name the argument y instead of x ?

Comment: Yeah that's not it, so conclusion: bug?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in betfair::getMarket()
in the first line: .bfapi(match.call(), service = service)

match.call() when called from g() gives: getMarket(marketId = x)
But x is not defined in getMarket().

To illustrate this, try this wrapper:

```
 h <- function(marketId){
   getMarket(marketId)
 }
 h(110501389)
```

Comment: I think that only works cause you have defined marketId in a global enviroment, before you call function.
rm(list=ls()), x<-110501389, h(x), and get back to me.

Comment: I could really test since I do not have an account.